# total no. of combinations of a column with other in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
 id_x             id_y
  a                 b
  b                 c
  c                 d
  d                 a
  b                 a
and so on around (1000 rows)
```

i want to find the count of combinations for each id_x with id_y.

ie. a has combinations with `a-b,d-a(total 2 combinations)`
similarly b has total `2 combinations(b-c) and also a-b to be considered as a combination for b( a-b = b-a)`

and create a dataframe df2 which has

```
id   combinations
a          2
b          2
c          2    #(c-d and b-c)
d          1
and so on ..(distinct product_id_'s)
```

i tried doing this code

```
df.groupby(['id_x']).size().reset_index()
```

but getting wrong result;

```
   id_x  0
0   a    1
1   b    1
2   c    1
3   d    1
```

what approach should i follow?
my skills on python are at a beginner level.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jezrael this is my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort all rows by `apply` `sorted`, then create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.apply(sorted,axis=1).drop_duplicates().stack().value_counts()
print (df)
d    2
a    2
b    2
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: but say, i have a-b and b-a, sorted would convert b-a to a-b, thus count of b that should be 2(b-c and b-a) is now only 1

Comment: @ i don't want the combination

Comment: Is `d` `2` ? Or not?

Comment: because `d-a` and `d-c`

Comment: yes, i am checking the code, can you explain me the logic that you've applied? i mean i don't know what `stack()` and `value_counts()` does